# Cannot read 'const char*' from python using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a simple function in a `c++` dynamic library which returns a `const char*` value. This value is assigned from a `string` type as shown in the code. I want to read the returned value of the function in a python script using **ctypes**:

#### C++

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <string>

#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" 
{
    EXPORT const char* sayHello()
    {
        std::string str = "hello world";
        const char* chptr = str.c_str();
        return chptr;
    }
}
```

#### Python

```py
from ctypes import *

lib = CDLL("c:\\mysource\\mylib.dll")

lib.sayHello.restype = c_char_p

buff = lib.sayHello()

print(buff)
```

Using this code, in python I get as a result:

```
b''
```

But when I change my cpp file and instead of using the `string` type and the conversion with `c_str()`, I assign the `"hello world"` directly into the `const char*`, it works ok:

```cpp
EXPORT const char* sayHello()
{
    const char* chptr = "hello world";
    return chptr;
}
```

... and I get as a result in python:

```
b'hello world'
```

Why when using a `string` variable, I receive an empty entry in python, but when using just the `const char*`, it works as expected?

Comment: Your first version of `sayHello` returns a dangling pointer.  The `std::string` object owns the memory it points to, and that memory gets freed when the `std::string` object goes out of scope.

Comment: `ctypes` is for C. For C++, use `pybind11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is destructing as you reach the end of your function block - and the memory for the associated `const char *` is getting freed.

```cpp
    EXPORT const char* sayHello()
    {
        std::string str = "hello world";
        const char* chptr = str.c_str(); // points to memory managed by str
        return chptr; // str gets destructed! This pointer points to dealloced memory
    }
```

In your other example, the `const char *` points to a string literal, which is likely in the .rodata segment, and so will outlive the scope of the function.

```cpp
EXPORT const char* sayHello()
{
    const char* chptr = "hello world"; // String literal
    return chptr; // Underlying memory isn't deallocated
}
```